# zend get with jQuery $.getJson

Tags: zend-framework

Does anyone know how to do this?

I want to point $.getJson() to a controller and have it return json through ajax based on request arguments. Unfortunately it appears Zend handles the get parameters different than jQuery encodes them.

How can I do this with Zend and jQuery? I saw something on stackoverflow about Post arguments but I am lost when it comes to GET.

When using jQuery I get a 404 error using this code:

---

Client side:

```
$.getJSON("/entry/get-member-course",
{
    "id": 1,
    "format": "json"
},
function(json) {
    alert("WIN");
});
```

Server side:

```
public function init() {
    $this->_helper->ajaxContext->addActionContext('get-member-course', 'json')->initContext();
}

public function getMemberCourseAction() {
    $this->view->test = Array("test"=>"bleh");        
}
```

Comment: See my updated answer. Also, show your client-side script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use context switching. In your controller, setup the [AjaxContext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.ajaxcontext) helper for your action with a "json" context

```
class EntryController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->_helper->ajaxContext->addActionContext('get-member-course', 'json')
                                   ->initContext();
    }

    public function getMemberCourseAction()
    {
        $id = $this->_getParam('id');

        $this->view->test = array('test' => 'bleh');
    }
}
```

The view for the calling script should contain a reference to the JSON URL. For example, say your JSON code is fired by clicking a link, create the link like this

```
<a id="get-json" href="<?php echo $this->url(array(
    'action'     => 'get-member-course',
    'controller' => 'entry',
    'id'         => $someId
), null, true) ?>">Click me for JSON goodness</a>
```

Your client-side code would have something like this

```
$('#get-json').click(function() {
    var url = this.href;
    $.getJSON(url, {
        "format": "json" // this is required to trigger the JSON context
    }, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // handle response here
    });
});
```

By default, when the JSON context is triggered, any view property is serialized as JSON and returned in the response. If your view properties cannot be simply converted, you need to disable automatic JSON serialization...

```
$this->_helper->ajaxContext->addActionContext('my-action', 'json')
                           ->setAutoJsonSerialization(false)
                           ->initContext();
```

and provide a JSON view script

```
// controllers/my/my-action.json.phtml
$simplifiedArray = array(
    'prop' => $this->someViewProperty->getSomeValue()
);
echo Zend_Json::encode($simplifiedArray);
```

Comment: How does Zend know how to interpret the argument string jQuery creates then?

Comment: @Walt What do you mean? You access the request parameters as shown in my answer. Perhaps show your JavaScript code so I've got an idea about what you're asking

Comment: For example: jQuery is going to issue the request with a query string like ?myParam=1&myParam2=2 whereas Zend is expecting /myParam/1/myParam2/2. Does what you mentioned circumvent that or do you have to just move all the arguments into the url for the request?

Comment: @Walt Zend handles either form so `my/my-action/param1/1/param2/2` is the same as `my/my-action?param1=1&param2=2`. The only thing to be wary of is that the former (route parameter) takes precedence so for `my/my-action/param/1?param=2`, the value of `param` via `Zend_Controller_Action::_getParam()` (which proxies to `Zend_Controller_Request_Http::getParam()`) will be `1`

Comment: Hmm looks like I get a 404 every time :(

Comment: @Walt What URL are you passing to `$.getJSON()`? If possible, it's best to set the URL via the Url view helper. You can set this in a JavaScript variable or even better, set it on an HTML anchor `href` or form `action` and pull it from there

Comment: I was using this url: /myController/action/
If I hit the url with the query string it renders my layout (which according to the documentation it shouldn't be doing with the context switch).

Comment: @Walt AjaxContext only triggers on AJAX requests. `myController` is an odd controller route name. Typically it would be `my-controller`. Perhaps post your updated code in your question

Comment: This is what the exact url that shows up in firbug is: http://127.0.0.1:8887/entry/getMemberCourse?id=1&format=json
This is the code:
`public function init() {
        $this->_helper->ajaxContext->addActionContext('getMemberCourse', 'json')->setAutoJsonSerialization(false)->initContext();
    }
 public function getMemberCourseAction() {
        $test = Array("test"=>"bleh");
        echo $test;
    }`

Comment: @Walt I'll re-iterate **Perhaps post your updated code in your question**. Both references to your action name (in URL and `addActionContext()`) should be `get-member-course`. You should also not be echo-ing from your action. Assign `$test` to the view. I'll update my answer

Comment: Looks like it works now... I guess it was because like you said, I was using getMemberCourse instead. Looks to be working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`getJSON` encodes a `JSON` string sequences such as `{Person:{name: "Ken", age: "24"}}`, do you have corresponding decoder on your server side?

[JSON PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

[Zend PHP JSON](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.html)

Comment: Yes. The problem is knowing how to get the arguments to the service though.